# Oracle Job deleted after execution

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm on oracle 11g

I created a job named "MyJob" to be ran at a fixed date/hour.

The job is well created.

When the job is executed correctly at the fixed date/hour, the job is apparently deleted from the table **dba_scheduler_jobs**, I verified with this query:

```
SELECT owner, job_name, enabled FROM dba_scheduler_jobs;
```

My question is why the job is "deleted" ?

My job creation script:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             => 'MyJobTest',
   job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action           => 'BEGIN insert into test values (''01'',sysdate); END;',
   start_date           => '01/12/16 17:00:00,000000000 +01:00',
   repeat_interval      => NULL, 
   end_date             => NULL,
   enabled              =>  TRUE,
   comments             => ' Insert into Test Table');
END;
```

/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show your code that creates a job?

Comment: It's a job wich insert into a table test: I updated my post with the script of creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a `repeat_interval` and the `auto_drop` parameter is set to `true` (the default if you don't specify the parameter at all), Oracle will drop the job once it is run.  Generally, if you're creating a job that runs once, there is no point in leaving it around forever.

You can tell Oracle not to auto drop the job by specifying an `auto_drop` value of false.

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             => 'MyJobTest',
   job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action           => 'BEGIN insert into test values (''01'',sysdate); END;',
   start_date           => '01/12/16 17:00:00,000000000 +01:00',
   repeat_interval      => NULL, 
   end_date             => NULL,
   enabled              =>  TRUE,
   auto_drop            => false,
   comments             => ' Insert into Test Table');
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. I understand :)